# How do I loop through question options so that I can assign a choice as correct and others as incorrect?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to create a spreadsheet where I am able to specify the answers to a given question.

I would like to set up my quiz so that I do not have to hard code which answers are correct and which are incorrect. At the moment, all this code does is store questions and options in variable and write them to a google form. Currently there is no functionality to check if the answer a user select is correct. Below is the part of the code in question, I think. At the moment, it takes the question and options from the spreadsheet, stored in a variable, and writes the question and possible options to a google form. How would I go about looping through the options and comparing each one to another variable called answer? If it is the same (option == answer), then specify that particular option as the answer and the rest as not.

I do realise that I would need to set the form as a quiz.

```
 //Add questions and options to form  
      for (qq=0;qq<numOfQs-1;qq++){
        var formQ = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        formQ.setTitle(questions[0][qq]);
        formQ.setChoiceValues(allOptions[qq]);
```

If this helps, below is the whole code which I have copied.

```
function createFormFromData() {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  //Get data, number of questions and options info
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numOfOptions = data.length-3;
  var numOfQs = data[0].length;

  //Get questions
  var questions = sh.getRange(2, 2, 1, numOfQs).getValues();

  //Get options and store in an array
  var allOptions = [];
  for (q=2;q<=numOfQs;q++){
    var options = sh.getRange(3, q, numOfOptions, 1).getValues();
    allOptions.push(options);
  }

  //Create the form
  var form = FormApp.create("New form");
  
  //Add questions and options to form  
  for (qq=0;qq<numOfQs-1;qq++){
    var formQ =
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

#### Update#1

So I have tried to continue my efforts to solve this issue. I thought I might try a combined for loop and if statement.

```
function makeMultipleQ(data) {
  var question = data [2]
  var questionNumber = data [0]
  var answer = data[9]
  Logger.log(answer)
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
  item.setTitle(questionNumber + '. ' + question)
  
  var trimmedData = data.filter(function(str) {
    return /\S/.test(str)
  })
  var slicedData = trimmedData.slice(3,trimmedData.length-1)
  var options = []
  for (var i = 0; i<slicedData.length;i++) {
    Logger.log(i)
    if (slicedData[i] == answer) {
      Logger.log('Yes')
      Logger.log(slicedData[i])
      options.push(item.createChoice(slicedData[i], true))
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('No')
    }
    }
```

I have changed the layout of the spreadsheet to accomodate different types of question in the Google form. The if statement at the moment says yes at the index of the answer if present in the loop; however, I cannot seem to set the answer as the correct answer if this occurs. Likewise, if the answer is not present in the array for it to be considered incorrect.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!! This is what my spreadsheet looks like now. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhFSN.jpg)

Comment: @|'-'| are you able to help?

Comment: @I'-'I, thank you for your comment. I apologise for the lack of clarity with the image. I have edited the post to include an image of my spreadsheet. There is a yellow column titled answers. The problem is that I do not know how to set an answer as 'is correct' if found within the choices array. This means that the quiz can be marked automatically. Presently, I would have to go into the Google form an create the answer key myself for all 46 questions. Whereas some sort of for loop would solve this in a few lines of code. Does that make sense? Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Script Flow:

- Get All data from spreadsheet
- Get each row of spreadsheet `data`
- Add Questions from Col3 `data[2]`
- Add all answers from Col4 to last Column `slicedData`
- Create array of choices with `createChoice(value,isCorrect)`
- `setChoice()` the array of choices.

#### Modified Script:

```
function makeMultipleQ(data) { //data- a row of spreadsheet dataRange
  var question = data[2]
  var questionNumber = data[0]
  var answer = data[9]
  Logger.log(answer)
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem(); //form to add choice
  item.setTitle(questionNumber + '. ' + question)
  var trimmedData = data.filter(function(str) {
    return /\S/.test(str)
  })
  var slicedData = trimmedData.slice(3, trimmedData.length - 1)
  var choices = []; //array of choices
  for (var i = 0; i < slicedData.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(i)
    if (slicedData[i] == answer) {
      Logger.log('Yes')
      Logger.log(slicedData[i])
      choices.push(item.createChoice(slicedData[i], true));//correct answer pushed to choices
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('No');
      choices.push(item.createChoice(slicedData[i],false)); //wrong answer pushed to choices
    }
  }
  item.setChoices(choices); //set the choices array to this itemQ
}
```

#### Notes:

- The loop is not necessary if the answer is always in the Col10 `data[9]`. You might wanna randomize that, if randomization is not already done by forms.
- If you're programmatically creating the form, You also need to enable Quiz mode by `setIsQuiz()`

#### References:

- [createChoice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createChoice(String,Boolean))
- [setChoices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setChoices(Choice))
- [setPoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setPoints(Integer))
- [setQuizMode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setIsQuiz(Boolean))